# Vue-auth websanova

Tags: authentication, vue.js, jwt

i'm trying to integrate JWT authentication in my client using websanova.

My problem is that on every http request, library is setting token of the response body. Here is my app.js configuration

```
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios)
Vue.use(VueAuth, {
  auth: {
    request: function (req, token) {
      req.headers['Authorization'] = 'JWT ' + token;
    },
    response: function (res) {
      return res.data
    }
  },
  http: require('@websanova/vue-auth/drivers/http/axios.1.x.js'),
  router: require('@websanova/vue-auth/drivers/router/vue-router.2.x.js'),
  loginData: { url: 'http://localhost:5005/api/authenticate', fetchUser: false },
  fetchData: { enabled: false },
  refreshData: { enabled: false },
  authRedirect: { path: '/' }
})
```

And i handle login like this

```
login () {
this.$store.dispatch("login");
var redirect = this.$auth.redirect();
  this.$auth.login({
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
data: this.data.body,
rememberMe: this.data.rememberMe,
redirect: { name: redirect ? redirect.from.name : 'Home' },
fetchUser: false,
success (res) {
  this.$store.dispatch("login_success");
},
err (err) { ...
```

Token is recived fine on login, but then when i want to display some table, token is overwriten by table source.

local storage before and after : 
[image: local storage before and after]

Comment: why dont you use [this package](https://github.com/websanova/vue-auth)?

Comment: it's exactly this package

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your app.js configuration inside your **auth**-> ***response*** function.

PROBLEM

```
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios)
Vue.use(VueAuth, {
  auth: {
    request: function (req, token) {
      req.headers['Authorization'] = 'JWT ' + token;
    },
    response: function (res) {
      return res.data   //HERE IS THE PROBLEM (You need to check the token and return it only when it is valid token)
    }
  },
  http: require('@websanova/vue-auth/drivers/http/axios.1.x.js'),
  router: require('@websanova/vue-auth/drivers/router/vue-router.2.x.js'),
  loginData: { url: 'http://localhost:5005/api/authenticate', fetchUser: false },
  fetchData: { enabled: false },
  refreshData: { enabled: false },
  authRedirect: { path: '/' }
})
```

SOLUTION

To solve it, you should check your token value **res.data** and then return it only if it is a *valid token*.
For example if the data return by the server after successfull authentication looks like **{'token': '123ABC'}** then your **auth**-> ***response*** function should look like this

```
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios)
Vue.use(VueAuth, {
  auth: {
    request: function (req, token) {
      req.headers['Authorization'] = 'JWT ' + token;
    },
    response: function (res) {

      //TEST IF DATA CONTAINS VALID AND RETURN IT. 
      if(res.data.token)
         return res.data.token  

      //DON'T RETURN ANY VALUE IF THERE IS NO VALID TOKEN
    }
  },
  http: require('@websanova/vue-auth/drivers/http/axios.1.x.js'),
  router: require('@websanova/vue-auth/drivers/router/vue-router.2.x.js'),
  loginData: { url: 'http://localhost:5005/api/authenticate', fetchUser: false },
  fetchData: { enabled: false },
  refreshData: { enabled: false },
  authRedirect: { path: '/' }
})
```

For more information you visite this page: [Vue-Auth custom auth drivers](https://github.com/websanova/vue-auth/blob/master/docs/Authentication.md)